# Software for drawing the shape of magnetic fields for different shaped magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, software

I've been looking for some time on the Internet, for software or some system in order to 
draw magnetic fields based on the geometry of a magnet. Is there a specific software for this? I hope this won't be a silly idea but how will be the geometry of the magnetic field of a Moebius strip? Or other shapes?